# numpy broadcasting two arrays of different shape to matrix

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have some machine learning examples as follows.

`T` is my training set. `T.shape = (t, 2)`: there are `t` examples, each with 2 parameters.

`X` is my input. `X.shape = (x, 2)`: `x` examples, each with 2 parameters.

What I want to do: Create a weight matrix `W` with `W.shape = (x, t)`, where each entry is the l2-norm of `x-t`.

For example: `W_(1,1) = np.linalg.norm(x[1]-t[1])`, `W_(3,5) = norm(x[3]-t[5])`, etc.

---

The provided solution broadcasts `X` into `(x, 1, 2)`:

```
a, b = x.shape
np.linalg.norm(t - np.reshape(x, (a, -1, b)), ord=2, axis=2)
```

I do not understand...

1. How a 3-D reshape works.
2. Why the choice `(x, 1, 2)`. Especially, please explain in details, ELI5, how broadcasting works, and why `(t, 2) - (x, 1, 2)` over `axis=2` produces the desired `(x, t)` matrix.

---

On a side note, my solution calculates the norm for each row, then concatenates them into a np.array:

```
l2_norm = np.array([np.linalg.norm(t - xi, axis=1, ord=2) for xi in x])
```

This works too, but I found out that over 100k trails, my solution performs 25% slower, 200 seconds to 250 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If your data had one dimension only, you could broadcast by operating a line against a column:

```
>>> T = np.random.random((4, 1))
>>> X = np.random.random((3, 1))
>>> T.T - X
array([[-0.39642429, -0.33396134,  0.01146835, -0.44301092],
       [-0.08324113, -0.02077818,  0.32465151, -0.12982776],
       [-0.1372684 , -0.07480545,  0.27062424, -0.18385503]])
```

If you look at the [General Broadcasting Rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules), you can interpret this as:

```
X     : 3, 1
T.T   : 1, 4
Result: 3, 4
```

With more dimensions,

```
>>> T = np.random.random((4, 2))
>>> X = np.random.random((3, 2))
```

you need the same 3x4 combinations plus the common 2 columns:

```
T               :    4, 2
X.reshape(3,1,2): 3, 1, 2
Result          : 3, 4, 2
```

The subtraction produces the required 3x4x2 array:

```
>>> T - X.reshape(3,1,2)
array([[[ 0.00216014, -0.04032913],
        [-0.17380644,  0.35771249],
        [-0.40192606,  0.25314362],
        [-0.5838469 ,  0.25939518]],
       [[-0.00597556, -0.17536056],
        [-0.18194214,  0.22268105],
        [-0.41006175,  0.11811218],
        [-0.5919826 ,  0.12436374]],
       [[ 0.55376845, -0.68902196],
        [ 0.37780187, -0.29098035],
        [ 0.14968226, -0.39554922],
        [-0.03223859, -0.38929765]]])
```

Then you calculate the norm along the last dimension (2), as in your example.

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(T - X.reshape(3,1,2), axis=2)
array([[0.04038694, 0.39770202, 0.47500131, 0.63887641],
       [0.17546235, 0.28755832, 0.42673309, 0.60490473],
       [0.88397441, 0.47686877, 0.42292312, 0.39063024]])
```